# Autocomplete with Django Haystack

Tags: django, autocomplete, routes, django-haystack

I am having a difficult time getting autocomplete to work with haystack and Solr in a search form. Following the instructions here [Auto-complete](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html) i was able to create my index in the following way.

```
class PersonIndex(indexes.RealTimeSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    first_name = CharField(model_attr='first_name')
    last_name = CharField(model_attr='last_name')
    first_name_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='first_name')


    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all().order_by('first_name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Person
```

And with the way my URL route is set up, i dont have a view request that get directed to, the search method works.

```
url(r'^search/person/', search_view_factory(
    view_class=SearchView,
    template='index.html',
    form_class=ModelSearchForm
), name='haystack_search'),
```

The instructions say that we can perform the query in this fashion

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))
```

but where do we put this SearchQuerySet, i am not sure what to override, how to modify my url to route correctly. My search currently works out of the box this way but i want to try auto complete with EdgeNgramField ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define your own custom search form and tell it how to generate the `SearchQuerySet` it returns to the view, and then tell your `search_view_factory` to use that form instead of the `ModelSearchForm`.

Specify the way you want to generate the `SearchQuerySet` used by your view by overriding the `ModelSearchForm` search method:

```
from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm

class AutocompleteModelSearchForm(ModelSearchForm):

    def search(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()
        if not self.cleaned_data.get('q')
            return self.no_query_found()
        sqs = self.searchqueryset.filter(first_name_auto=self.cleaned_data['q'])

        if self.load_all
            sqs = sqs.load_all()

        return sqs
```

This will now perform a filter on the form's `SearchQuerySet` on the `first_name_auto` field rather than the `auto_query` that it would usually do on the `text` field (see `haystack/forms.py` to see what the original search function looks like).

You specify that you want to use this form in the argument list to your `search_view_factory`

```
from path.to.your.forms import AutocompleteModelSearchForm

url(r'^search/person/', search_view_factory(
    view_class=SearchView,
    template='index.html',
    form_class=AutocompleteModelSearchForm
 ), name='haystack_search'),
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed answer. I am able to follow the search method which looks mostly the same as the haystack one with the auto set to it. The problem i am having now is that i can't pull any data back. I am not sure how to debug this, if i go back to the basic ModelSearchForm it works

Comment: No problem. Can you clarify what you mean by 'able to follow the search method which looks mostly the same as the haystack one with the auto set to it'? 

Can you give me an example of the query you have in 'q', and the data you expect it to match?

Comment: I meant the example from haystack/forms.py, basically using the one you specified in your example. As i start typing into the text field, nothing happens. When i press enter, i got an error about 'AutocompleteModelSearchForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_date'

Comment: Ah, 'cleaned_date' should be 'cleaned_data'. I made a type-o. Fixed that in the answer.

As for the behaviour you're expecting (results appearing as you type), this isn't functionality provided by Haystack. Haystack autocomplete simply matches queries containing a substring to whole words in the field you're searching.

If you're after the dynamic, drop-down-as-you-type autocomplete, you'll need to use some Javascript. [JQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is a good place to start. Haystack autocomplete can provide the server side stuff for this.

Comment: Okay, got it. So whats the usage of this autocomplete and now i am getting this error 'AutocompleteModelSearchForm' object has no attribute 'load_All'

Comment: Sorry never mind, can i have more than one filter, first name and last name

Comment: 'load_All' is another type-o. Fixed.

Comment: Maybe submit any extra questions not related to the original question as a new question so they're easier for people to find?

Comment: Thanks again, i will look into the jquery client side auto complete